# emacs auto completion el file error

Tags: debugging, emacs, cygwin, elisp, xemacs

I'm very new to emacs, just started yesterday.
I'm installing plugins for emacs to make a `python IDE`, as per:  http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/

I copied auto-completion.el to `~/.emacs.d/plugins/` directory,
I pasted the code that they had in my `~/.xemacs/init.el`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")  
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/plugins/auto-completion.el") ; <- did this later when it couldn't find the file
```

```lisp
(require 'auto-complete)  
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

but it gave me an error:

> Symbol's function definition is void: define-global-minor-mode

So far my biggest problem has been along the lines of the above one:

If any of the el file in `~/.emacs.d/` have errors, it asks me to open a
`xemacs -debug-init` but that always produces a blank screen instead of a stacktrace.

There's no way for me to figure out where the error came from.
How do i test individual functions within these `el` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to imply you're using XEmacs?  I would start over with GNU Emacs if
that's the case.  They are not interchangeable.

Most of the help and blogs and what not from the INTERNETS are for GNU Emacs.
Most packages only maintain conpatibility with GNU Emacs.  XEmacs development
has also been stagnant for quite a while.

EDIT: apparently I didn't use strong enough language.

[image: dead end]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Dead_End_sign.svg/220px-Dead_End_sign.svg.png))</sub>

---

## XEmacs has ceased development.

---

## NO package you encounter will likely be compatible with it.

---

## As a new user, there is no *choice* as to which Emacs to use.  It's just GNU Emacs.

---

I have nothing against XEmacs.  I am a former XEmacs user.  This is just reality.

Comment: emacs didn't seem to work well in windows7 (i couldn't even do Ctrl-C) so i switched to xemacs

Comment: Emacs works fine on Windows7.  If you have trouble configuring it, you should ask questions about that.  My point is XEmacs is a dead end for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer to more strongly declare why XEmacs is not appropriate for your use.  If after reading this, you still want to proceed with XEmacs.  May Jeebus be with you!  ;)

Comment: i got emacs to work, it was just a cygwin issue, i can see stacktraces here alteast

Comment: I use a native build of Emacs on windows, with cygwin tools in the PATH.  From what I understand this is very common.